# Is there a way to redefine/disable self.new?

Tags: resources, instance, crystal-lang

I'm trying to figure out a way to safely free resources acquired by a class. I tried using `finalize`, but it's unreliable. Sometimes I close my program before GC has a chance to free resources.

So I decided to use class instance in a block like this:

```
class Foo

  def destroy # free resources
      #...
  end

  #...

  def self.create(*args)
      instance = self.new(*args)
      begin
        yield instance
      ensure
        instance.destroy
      end
end

Foo.create do |foo|
  # use foo
end
```

That works fine, but I still can create an instance using `new` that I'd have to `destroy` explicitly. I tried to write my own `new` but it seems like it's just overloaded by default `new`.

Is there a way to redefine\disable `new`?

Comment: This is not `ruby`, I can't make `.new` private. I guess it's overloaded by default `.new`.

Comment: @Anon Apologies. I thought I was filtering on the [Ruby] tag. I've deleted the comments.

Comment: @WPeN2Ic850EU please write that as a full answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is `initialize` method, that should be made `private`:

```
class Foo
  @foo : String

  private def initialize(@foo)
  end

  def destroy
    puts "Destroying #{self}"
  end

  def self.create(arg)
    instance = new(arg)
    yield instance
  ensure
    instance.destroy if instance
  end
end

Foo.create("bar") do |foo| # will work
  p foo
end

Foo.new("bar")             # will raise
```

[Playground](https://carc.in/#/r/42fr)